# Spring Custom SSO

Tags: spring, jasper-reports, single-sign-on, jasperserver

I am trying to integrate two separate web applications - one is an existing custom web application with it's own security paradigm and the other is a reporting platform (JasperServer). I want to be able to use Jasper's web services interface to integrate the reporting functionality into our application. Our security model is complex and is home grown but I think there is hope.

We set a cookie that is an encrypted string containing a web service URI as the authentication source and a token which is stored in the database that is created when the user logs in and is destroyed when he/she logs out. I think I can leverage this to implement a kind of SSO in Jasper since it uses Spring Security.

What I *THINK* I should do is implement a pre-authentication filter that checks for the cookie I mentioned above. It could then decrypt it, make a web service call to the authentication source provided to verify the token is active in the database. If it is, that token can be used to point to user and role information that could be returned as a UserDetails object.

Unfortunately, I know enough to be dangerous but not enough to be effective. Am I on the right track? Does this solution sound tenable? If so, where would be a good place to start and are there any examples of something similar you could point me to? I've searched around quite a bit and have found nothing that quite fits the bill.

Thanks in advance to any and all who can provide me a glimmer of hope

Comment: Do the two servers share the same domain or hostname?

Comment: Not necessarily. In fact, in many cases they will not so I suppose I should answer no.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are tied to a domain/subdomain/path and port. It is possible to set a cookie at the domain level so if you have something like webapp.mydomain.com and jasper.mydomain.com you may be ok assuming they are on the same port.

However be **very** careful about implementing your own SSO/Authentication framework. It requires a great deal of thought. As it stands your proposed implementation would be vulnerable to: replay, man in the middle, and XSRF attacks ... there may be other vulnerabilities but these are just 3 that come to mind ... sorry! :D